# mixing version can lead to runtime crashes?

Tags: android

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

All `com.android.support` libraries must use exact same version specification. Mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes.

Found versions 27.1.1, 27.1.0. Examples include `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1` and `com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0`

Please help me to solve this problem...

Comment: you're using conflicting support versions, one is 27.1.1 while the other is 27.1.0, all support dependency versions should be exactly the same. if that didn't work try cleaning your project and attempt rebuilding.

Answer (score 3):

The issue usually rises when third-party libraries are using an older version of the support library. You can get over it by looking at which lib is using the older version and add this to your build gradle on the app level

```
implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1"
```

In my case, it was the Facebook SDK so I replace this

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0'
```

with

```
implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0') {
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
}
```

and all my warnings disappeared

Answer (score 0):

27.1.1 is the latest version of the Android support library. So just replace the version to 27.1.1 for all com.android.support dependencies you're using. No reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

I completed the answers of Mukesh Solanki with:

```
    dependencies{
        implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.1'){
                // contains com.android.support:v7:27.0.2, included required com.android.support.*:27.1.1 modules
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
            }
            implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1"
            implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1"
            implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1"
        }


}
```

And all my problem when away